# Cant connect to remote DB using EntityData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity

I am using ASP.NET Core, and want to use EntityFramework to get data from DB.
I use next "appsettings.json"

```
    {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MeteodataContex": "Server=77.222.146.91;Port=2800;Database=forecast;Uid=vntu_root;Pwd=politehluchevseh;"
  }
}
```

and the next class to connect database

```
namespace WebSolaris.Models
{
    public class MeteodataContex : DbContext
    {               public MeteodataContex() : base("MeteodataContex")
        { 

}
      public DbSet<t_meteodata> meteodatas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the class which get the data

```
namespace WebSolaris.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SomeMeteoDataController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult Get(int stationId, DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            from = from.ToUniversalTime();
            to = to.ToUniversalTime();
            var met = new MeteoViewModel();
            List<t_meteodata> responsemeteo;
            using (var sd = new MeteodataContex())
            {
                {
                    responsemeteo = sd.meteodatas.Where(x => from <= x.DateTimeCr && x.DateTimeCr <= to)
                        .OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeCr)
                        .ToList();
                    met.SolarRadiation = responsemeteo.ToDictionary(x => x.DateTimeCr, z => z.SolarRadiation);
                    met.WindSpeed = responsemeteo.ToDictionary(x => x.DateTimeCr, z => z.WindSpeed);
                    met.Wetness = responsemeteo.ToDictionary(x => x.DateTimeCr, z => z.Wetness);
                    met.TemperatureC = responsemeteo.ToDictionary(x => x.DateTimeCr, z => z.TemperatureC);
                }
                   return Ok(met);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect SQL server or mysql databse server?

Comment: connect to mysql

Comment: What error are you getting in the code? Are you able to connect to the server from workbench? Are you sure that the db server is available at port 2800?

Comment: Yes, i can connect with mysql workbench  NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.    at line {responsemeteo = sd.meteodatas.Where(x => from <= x.DateTimeCr && x.DateTimeCr <= to)}

Comment: It looks like the EF is trying to use SQL server provider and connect to sql server...  With that MySql connectionstring won't work. Can you tell us how did you generate the EF model in first place?